Why am I getting OAuthAccountNotLinked error in Next Auth with Next.js 13?
Trying to resolve my login issue I did a lot of research and testing through these Q&As:

NextAuth - OAuthAccountNotLinked - Imported data from another website - Autolinking
OAuthAccountNotLinked error in next-auth with Nextjs 13
Next js - Next Auth - Keep having error=OAuthCreateAccount google provider
How to handle OAuthAccountNotLinked error in a Next.js app with NextAuth, Prisma, and MongoDB?
NextAuth - Secondth time signing in with the same google account, OAuthAccountNotLinked error
Next-auth does not detect linked account after first sign in OAuthAccountNotLinked
How to handle OAuthAccountNotLinked error in next-auth with Nextjs 13
next-auth google signin issue OAuthAccountNotLinked caus of MongoDBAdapterOptions.collections
Next js - Next Auth - Keep having error=OAuthCreateAccount google provider

However, when I run my Next.js application and try to log in I keep getting the error message of:

Try signing in with a different account.

route url in Chrome browser: http://localhost:3000/api/auth/signin?error=OAuthAccountNotLinked
route.js
filepath: app/api/auth/[...nextauth]/route.ts
contents:
import NextAuth from 'next-auth'
import GoogleProvider from 'next-auth/providers/google'
import type { NextAuthOptions } from 'next-auth'
import { PrismaAdapter } from '@next-auth/prisma-adapter'
import prisma from '@/prisma/client'

export const authOptions: NextAuthOptions = {
  adapter: PrismaAdapter(prisma),
  providers: [
    GoogleProvider({
      clientId: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID!,
      clientSecret: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET!,
      allowDangerousEmailAccountLinking: true,
    }),
  ],
  session: {
    strategy: 'jwt',
  },
}

const handler = NextAuth(authOptions)

export { handler as GET, handler as POST }

prisma schema
path: prisma/schema.prisma
pulled from here, file contents:
generator client {
  provider = "prisma-client-js"
}

datasource db {
  provider = "mysql"
  url      = env("DATABASE_URL")
}

model User {
  id            String          @id @default(cuid())
  name          String?
  email         String          @unique
  emailVerified DateTime?
  image         String?
  accounts      Account[]
  sessions      Session[]
 
  createdAt DateTime @default(now())
  updatedAt DateTime @updatedAt
}
 
model Account {
  userId            String
  type              String
  provider          String
  providerAccountId String
  refresh_token     String?
  access_token      String?
  expires_at        Int?
  token_type        String?
  scope             String?
  id_token          String?
  session_state     String?
 
  createdAt DateTime @default(now())
  updatedAt DateTime @updatedAt
 
  user User @relation(fields: [userId], references: [id], onDelete: Cascade)
 
  @@id([provider, providerAccountId])
}
 
model Session {
  sessionToken String   @unique
  userId       String
  expires      DateTime
  user         User     @relation(fields: [userId], references: [id], onDelete: Cascade)
 
  createdAt DateTime @default(now())
  updatedAt DateTime @updatedAt
}
 
model VerificationToken {
  identifier String
  token      String
  expires    DateTime
 
  @@id([identifier, token])
}

prisma client
path: prisma/client.ts
contents:
import { PrismaClient } from '@prisma/client'

const prismaClientSingleton = () => {
  return new PrismaClient()
}

declare global {
  var prismaGlobal: undefined | ReturnType<typeof prismaClientSingleton>
}

const prisma = globalThis.prismaGlobal ?? prismaClientSingleton()

export default prisma

if (process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production') globalThis.prismaGlobal = prisma

package.json dependencies
  "dependencies": {
    "@auth/prisma-adapter": "^2.0.0",
    "@next-auth/prisma-adapter": "^1.0.7",
    "@prisma/client": "^5.13.0",
    "@types/node": "20.12.7",
    "@types/react": "18.2.79",
    "@types/react-dom": "18.2.25",
    "autoprefixer": "10.4.19",
    "eslint": "8.57.0",
    "eslint-config-next": "14.2.2",
    "fast-sort": "^3.4.0",
    "next": "14.2.2",
    "next-auth": "^4.24.7",
    "next-cloudinary": "^6.5.1",
    "postcss": "8.4.38",
    "prisma": "^5.13.0",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "18.2.0",
    "tailwindcss": "3.4.3",
    "typescript": "5.4.5",
    "zod": "^3.23.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "daisyui": "^4.10.2"
  }

I've tried with both @auth/prisma-adapter and @next-auth/prisma-adapter but nothing is logged to the console. Don't see anything in Chrome app dashboard either.
Why can I not sign in with Google using Next Auth?
